# cómo colocar la ruta de navegación de mi proceso de react en hostinger?

Tags: reactjs, rutas, dominio, host

estoy hosteando un sitio web creado con React y localmente funciona muy bien, sin embargo, ya en el dominio, mis botones de redirección URL no me navegan correctamente entre mi página, me aparece error 404. ¿Cómo especifico la dirección de mis páginas estando en el dominio?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './index.css';
import Home from './pages/home';
import Donate from './pages/Donate';
import AboutUs from './pages/AboutUs';
import News from './pages/News';
import ContactUs from './pages/ContactUs';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
{
 path: '/',
 element: <Home />
},
{
 path: '/Donate',
 element: <Donate />
},
{
  path: '/AboutUs',
  element: <AboutUs />
},
{
  path: '/News',
  element: <News />
},
{
  path: '/ContactUs',
  element: <ContactUs />
},

]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>

  <RouterProvider router={router}/>

  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Hola , podrías agregar más información con respecto a los botones, por favor. No se si usas react hook pero en los componentes declaras `useNavigate()` para luego usar `navigate(“/laruta”)` en el onclick del botón?